# Traveling Salesperson tour monotonicity

Tags: computational-geometry

Prove that the travelling salesperson tour TSP of a set S of points
is monotone, that is, if S ⊆ S′, then the length of
TSP(S) is less than or equal to the length of TSP(S′).

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: I don't have idea in this problem. I don't know where to start. Can you help me?

Comment: How do you define a travelling salesperson tour?

Comment: Is it from one point going to another point and your objective is to go to all the points once and going back to the origin. Is that it?

Comment: Can you help me sir with this problem? I am stack in it. Thank you so much sir for your response. @Servaes